# How to determine if java.sql.Connection is valid with PostgreSQL JDBC4

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying write a test for a method that returns a java.sql.Connection to connect to a PostgreSQL.

My test is very straightforward:

```
@Test
public void connectionFactoryShouldReturnOpenConnection() throws Exception {
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();

    assertTrue(conn.isValid(2));
}
```

The `isValid` call fails, though:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(int) is not yet implemented.
at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:753)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:109)
at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.isValid(Jdbc4Connection.java:21)
```

What's going on?  Surely there is a PostgreSQL JDBC driver that implements the methods of Java 1.6 such as `isValid()`?

Here the details on the driver I'm using:

```
<groupId>postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
```

Comment: I wonder if this is a case of: it didn't exist before 1.6, so all connection pool implementations support specifying a statement to execute to test the connection. Now since connection pools all support that, there isn't much demand for drivers that support the new method? Kind of perverse, but that's life.

Comment: @EricWilson - It appears that isValid() was implemented starting in version 9.2.1000 (released September 27, 2012) of the driver (I apologize for the double-notification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform a simple query, if it works, it's valid. If not, it's not.

And by simple query I mean something like:

```
SELECT 1;
```

Really simple.

Comment: If there is no other option, I'll go with that.  But it doesn't make me confident in my driver to find such a simple method not implement.

Comment: bad idea, select 1 on a table with >2 mio rows becomes super slow... is there a way to disable this test connection thing at all?

Comment: you use just "select 1" without any table. And this will return "1". Very quick query.

Answer (score 2):

From the postresql driver [source code](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-jdbc-9.0-801.src.tar.gz) the `AbstractJdbc4Connection.isValid()` throws this exception when called:

```
public boolean isValid(int timeout) throws SQLException
{
    checkClosed();
    throw org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(this.getClass(), "isValid(int)");
}
```

Comment: That is interesting, and confirms my experience, but doesn't answer the question of how a connection can be best verified using Java JDBC and Postgres.